# OpenEJB - replace the "classpath.ear" by other name

Tags: ejb-3.0, openejb

The app I'm working have a custom ServiceLocator, so, I need to be able to specify the name I want for the app.

In other words, instead of bind the EJB's to:

```
java:global/classpath.ear/project-name/JNDI
```

I want to bind it to:

```
java:global/myapp/project-name/JNDI
```

Setting `javax.ejb.embeddable.appName` in `jndi.properties`, passing it to `new InitialContext(Properties)` or as a `System` property doesn't seem to take any effect.

BTW: I'm using OpenEJB embedded for tests.

Thanks in advance.